# How can I display collected amount of coins without overflow (accessing another script) in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, stack-overflow

I have two scripts. **PlayerMove.cs** and **Spawner.cs** .
In PlayerMove.cs I want a function that changes the text to the number of coins.

```
void CountCoin()
{
    cointext.text = ": "+ coincount;
    CountCoin();
}
```

In Spawner.cs I spawn coins and I want to increase coincount(which is public variable of PlayerMove.cs) each time I spawn.

```
IEnumerator StartSpawningCoins ()
    {
        coin.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled=true;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(6f, 16f));

        GameObject k = Instantiate(coin);

        // my problem starts here

        GameObject Player = GameObject.Find("PlayerMove");
        PlayerMove playermove = Player.GetComponent<PlayerMove>();
        playermove.coincount++;

        //till here

        float x = Random.Range(min_X,max_X);

        k.transform.position = new Vector2(x, transform.position.y);

        StartCoroutine(StartSpawningCoins());
    }
```

When I use these I get stack overflow error. How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the name of the gameobject to which PlayerMove script is attached?

Comment: ...It is Player

Comment: void CountCoin()
{
    cointext.text = ": "+ coincount;
    CountCoin();
} Remove the function call to CountCoin() in this function and check. the CountCoin function is getting called infinitely here

Comment: `CountCoin()` calls itself, with no exit condition, so you end up in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in

```
void CountCoin()
{
    cointext.text = ": "+ coincount;
    CountCoin();
}
```

you call `CountCoin()` itself!

---

If you wanted a repeated Update you could e.g. use [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html)

```
void CountCoin()
{
    cointext.text = ": "+ coincount;

    // calls this method again after 1 second
    Invoke(nameof(CountCoin), 1f);
}
```

or directly [`InvokeRepeating`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)

```
void Start()
{
    // calls CountCoin every second, the first time after 1 second delay
    InvokeRepeating(nameof(CountCoin), 1f, 1f);
}
```

in order to call it every second.

Or simply remove the nested call entirely and add one to [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) to make it get called every frame

```
void Update()
{
    CountCoin();
}
```

**Or** this is what I would rather do: Make `coincount` a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) and add the according behavior to the setter:

```
private int _coincount;
public int coincount 
{
    get { return _coincount; }
    set 
    { 
        _coincount = value;
        cointext.text = ": "+ value;
    }
}
```

so everytime you change the property the code is executed automatically

---

Btw `Find` is quite expensive and should be avoided. I would change your code to

```
private PlayerMove playermove;

IEnumerator StartSpawningCoins ()
{
    // as long as you yield inside this is ok
    while(true)
    {
        // only do find if needed
        if(!player) player = GameObject.Find("PlayerMove");

        // this should probably actually be done in the prefab not via code
        coin.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(6f, 16f));

        GameObject k = Instantiate(coin);
        playermove.coincount++;

        float x = Random.Range(min_X,max_X);

        k.transform.position = new Vector2(x, transform.position.y);
    }
}
```